# HTML div growing beyond max-height of parent container

Tags: html, css

I know there are tons of questions asking the same thing but none of the solutions I came across works for the scenario that I set up.

I have a simple structure that has one main outer div, and a inner div. Within the inner div I separated into two of 10% and 90% height respectively. The second separation seems to grow beyond the restrictions set by max-height and I can't seem to figure out why.

**EDIT**
I need for the scroll bar to be present in the second separation (.content) and not on the inner div (.main-body)

```css
.outer-layer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  z-index: 15000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.main-body {
  position: fixed;
  top: 18%;
  left: 18%;
  background: #fff;
  width: 60%;
  min-height: 30%;
  max-height: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.header {
  height: 10%;
  max-height: 10%;
  background: red;
}
.content {
  max-height: 90%;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 90%;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-layer">
  <div class="main-body">
    <div class="header">
      <h2>Hello</h2>
      <!--header-->
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>dynamic content</p>
      <p>dynamic content</p>
      <p>dynamic content</p>
      <p>dynamic content</p>
      <p>dynamic content</p>
      <p>dynamic content</p>
      <!--content-->
    </div>
    <!--body-->
  </div>
  <!--overlay-->
</div>
```

I am currently testing in Chrome

I included this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nu5LkL6b/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [**this JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/nu5LkL6b/7/) what you're aiming for?

You had a few slight hiccups in your original version that I've tidied up and outlined below...

**1.** You cannot use a percentage-based height on an element whose parent does not have a set height. Because you are not giving `.main-body` a set height, its children will not respect percentage-based heights. This is resolved by giving `.main-body` a height.

**2.** Your `<h2>` has large vertical margins, and so its height is expanding past the height of its parent. Remove these by doing `h2 {margin: 0;}`.

**3.** Remember that padding is *additive*! 10px padding on both the top and bottom of an element will add 20px to its height. You can use `box-sizing: border-box;` on your elements to avoid this - it forces the element to apply their padding *inwards* instead of *outwards*, thereby not messing with it's height/width.

Comment: I was a bit unfair to include the h2 tag in the fiddle but good eye. I actually used a styled span tag in my actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

The page needs to render the information regardless.  Assuming that the inner content is larger than the outer, using `overflow` creates a scroll bar for you.

```
.main-body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

---

Post edit Updates:

```
.header {
  position:fixed;
  width: 60%;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 10%; // To match the header's height
}
```

The styling will be off, but you can adjust it to fit your project better.

Comment: In this case, this is *not* the issue. Changing the overflow will have no effect.

Comment: Sorry I left out one bit of my question initially. Please see update

Answer (score 0):

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nu5LkL6b/9/

As discussed: You cannot use a percentage-based height on an element whose parent does not have a set height. Because you are not giving .main-body a set height, its children will not respect percentage-based heights. This is resolved by giving .main-body a height.

Little Enhc:

```
.content {
  max-height: 90%;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(90% - 20px);
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

CSS:

```
.outer-layer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  z-index: 15000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.main-body {
  position: fixed;
  top: 18%;
  left: 18%;
  background: #fff;
  width: 60%;
  min-height: 30%;
  height: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.header {
  height: 10%;
  max-height: 10%;
  background: red;
}
.content {
  max-height: 90%;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(90% - 20px);
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `h2` has "native" margin which is added to the `main-body` height and breaks the percentage. Remove this margin. Then your `main-body` has padding that add extra pixels too. Remove it, and `90% + 10%` will fit `100%`.

```css
h2 {
    margin: 0;
}

.outer-layer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  z-index: 15000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.main-body {
  position: fixed;
  top: 18%;
  left: 18%;
  background: #fff;
  width: 60%;
  min-height: 30%;
  max-height: 60%;
}
.header {
  height: 10%;
  max-height: 10%;
  background: red;
}
.content {
  max-height: 90%;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 90%;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-layer">
  <div class="main-body">
    <div class="header">
      <h2>Hello</h2>
      <!--header-->
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>dynamic content</p>
      <p>dynamic content</p>
      <p>dynamic content</p>
      <p>dynamic content</p>
      <p>dynamic content</p>
      <p>dynamic content</p>
      <!--content-->
    </div>
    <!--body-->
  </div>
  <!--overlay-->
</div>
```

Comment: I believe OP's issue is that the blue div should have a max-height, and *not* expand to the length of its content.

Comment: @Santi He don't really says what he expect. We have to guess. I think both my and your interpretation and answers are valids.

Comment: He said "The second separation seems to grow beyond the restrictions set by max-height and I can't seem to figure out why."

Comment: @Santi, yes and both my answer and yours and overflow: hidden/scroll on main-body makes that "the second separation don't grow beyond the restrictions set by max-height"...

Comment: Take a look at a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nu5LkL6b/4/) of your answer. The white div's height in your example is 402px. The blue div's height - having a max-height of 90% - is 1600px. I don't believe your example resolves "The second separation growing beyond the restrictions set by max-height".

Comment: AlFoиceѫ sorry for the confusion but @Santi seems to get the idea of what I was trying to relay

Answer (score -1):

you need to add height to the parent element i.e `.main-body`

```
 .main-body{
        height:72%;    /* added */
        padding:0px;  /* editied  */
    }
    .header{
      height:20%;   /* edited*/
      max-height:20%; /* edited but actually not needed to have max height */
    }
```